# Is gql-response READ_ONLY? If yes then why so?

Tags: angular, graphql, graphql-js, apollo-client

```
constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {}    

ngOnInit(){
    /* -- apollo query setup--- */             
    const subscriber = this.apollo.query<any>(this.options);
    subscriber.subscribe((data) => {
        data.data.id = 'demo'
    } 
}
```

Error:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'id' of object '[object Object]'
>   TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'id' of object '[object Object]'

Comment: please add you'r code to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: Actually, I cant share my code.  Say for example If I am getting below json in response
 
{
  "data": {
    "allComments": [
      {
        "id": "cja6h44lr9xrz0156ieb7hs5r"
      },
      {
        "id": "cjbdvs5qz3kxl0130xf7rhop6"
      },
      {
        "id": "cjcrtl75go3m80112fymxpj6d"
      },
      {
        "id": "cjf094sb1uf5p0134aznxgkqu"
      },
      {
        "id": "cjg51q77k8zuw01626blnxfem"
      }
]

And I want to update  data.allComments[0].id, then I am getting similar error

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of the same reason as in Redux, NGRX or any other thing that has a store. You don't want to touch or mutate the store directly.

NGRX by default does not freeze the object so that's why you won't get any errors but they strongly recommend to avoid mutating the results.

Imagine when the result would be mutable and you would change a property there. It will reflect to the store.